# Sort result with empty strings first

Tags: mysql, database

I have this `locations` table:

```
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
| id |  country  |   state    |   city   |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
|  1 |  US       | Georgia    |  Atlanta |
|  2 |  US       | California |          |
|  3 |  US       |            |          |
|  4 |  Canada   |  Ontario   |          |
|  5 |  Canada   |  Manitoba  | Winnipeg |
|  6 |  Canada   |            |          |
```

I want to create a query but could not build my `ORDER BY` properly. This is the result that I want:

```
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
| id |  country  |   state    |   city   |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
|  6 |  Canada   |            |          |
|  3 |  US       |            |          |
|  4 |  Canada   | Ontario    |          |
|  2 |  US       | California |          |
|  5 |  Canada   | Manitoba   | Winnipeg |
|  1 |  US       | Georgia    | Atlanta  |
```

Basically, this is the priority that I want to follow:

1. Country listing. Alphabetical order.
2. State listing. Alphabetical order.
3. City listing. Alphabetical order.

This query does not seem to account for empty columns (I am not using NULLs in my `locations` table):

```
SELECT * FROM locations
ORDER BY 
    country,state,city
```

Comment: This looks more like an alternating order

Comment: Do you think this kind of operation is heavy on CPU? I'm contemplating to pre-order my table.

Comment: If you need this ordering only for display purposes (without pagination); I would rather do it in the application code (eg: PHP); MySQL *may not* be able to utilize index in this case, thus burdening CPU.

Comment: @user1506104 There is no concept of pre-ordering your table data in SQL.  The closest thing to what you have in mind would be to create an index which lets your database sort the data the way you want to see it.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya,i have all the places in the world and im paginating so i dont send every location to my app. I believe my best option is do the ordering in my sql query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "no concept of pre-ordering". i learned something today.

Comment: @user1506104 If you are paginating, then SQL query is the way. If the data in this table is not dynamic (generally should not be; if you have already accounted for all the places in the world), then you can repopulate this table in the specific order you need. And then use the autoincrement key to fetch the data. Otherwise, this particular type of complex sorting may not be able to utilize any index.

Comment: *"If you are paginating, then SQL query is the way"* @MadhurBhaiya depends how the SQL is written and number of records in the table.. Most will use `LIMIT 1000000, 1000` as that feels like the most natural thing to do in MySQL to paginate but thats terrible for performance as MySQL databases needs to fetch 1001000 records...

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes; What is the workaround in this case ? Although in most practical applications, no user would be really going to 1000th page..unless that user is trying to dig a lot deeper...

Comment: *"What is the workaround in this case ? Although in most practical applications, no user would be really going to 1000th page..unless that user is trying to dig a lot deeper... "* Search engines can and will go that deep..  @MadhurBhaiya the general approach is to use the PRIMARY KEY and auto_increment column, use ORDER BY on the column as well as while to keep the results 100% deterministic (fixed) and track of the id in the application.. more or less like `WHERE id >= 1000000 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have started using similar approach sometime back..does not work in all the cases though..thanks for the tip!

Comment: *"does not work in all the cases though.."* @MadhurBhaiya also a option is to deploy a window function on MySQL 8 to make a ranking/order (with `RANK()/ROW_NUMBER()`) resultset and "limit" (filter) on that.  Or simulate it with  MySQL user variables on lower versions.. This should extend the possible user cases vs the other method.. in fact using a window function to "limit" resultsets was one of the only valid ANSI/ISO SQL standard solution until SQL 2016 defined `FETCH` to limit resultsets or delivered tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM locations
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN state = '' AND city = '' THEN 0
         WHEN city = '' THEN 1
         ELSE 2 END,
    country,
    state,
    city;
```

This sorting logic places first those records which are missing both state and city.  Next follows records missing city only, followed last by records having non empty data for all three fields.

Answer (score 1):

For versions pre 8.0...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,state VARCHAR(20) NULL
,city VARCHAR(20) NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'US','Georgia','Atlanta'),
(2,'US','California',NULL),
(3,'US',NULL,NULL),
(4,'Canada','Ontario',NULL),
(5,'Canada','Manitoba','Winnipeg'),
(6,'Canada',NULL,NULL);

SELECT id
     , country
     , state
     , city 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev=country THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev:=country 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY country
            , city
            , state
     ) a 
 ORDER 
    BY i
     , country;
+----+---------+------------+----------+
| id | country | state      | city     |
+----+---------+------------+----------+
|  6 | Canada  | NULL       | NULL     |
|  3 | US      | NULL       | NULL     |
|  4 | Canada  | Ontario    | NULL     |
|  2 | US      | California | NULL     |
|  5 | Canada  | Manitoba   | Winnipeg |
|  1 | US      | Georgia    | Atlanta  |
+----+---------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: thanks for the effort. i will try this out later (as i already have an accepted answer). if this works, i can give you a bounty instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from locations
order by 
  state <> '',
  city  <> '',
  country,
  state,
  city
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j7wn8F3uwwqw6qYWWFJPAH/0)

Note that in MySQL a boolean expression returns `0` (for `FALSE`) or `1` (for `TRUE`). That means for an empty `state` string `state <> ''` will return `0` and thus ordered first.